# How to get this splash effect in the fluid simulation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, fluid-simulation

I'm Tying to make this animation in which a cookie flies and splashes into a coffee cup, but something's not right. The cookie makes the fall in one and a half secod (If in 30fps) but even at 256 resolution divisions, the coffee in the cup just wobbles very slightly and doesn't even think of splashing. I currently cannot provide the images of the fluid since I freed the bake, but this is the setup:

There is a coffee cup that falls on a table (There is a cup on a plate, and in it there is some liquid which is perfectly fitted to the cup. I added a cuboid as a fluid domain set the resolution divisions to 256, and then set the fluid in the cup as a fluid inflow.) and a cookie flies off a plate and is supposed to splash (If only the fluid did) into the cup.

The cookie falls using keyframes. The cookie and coffee cup are not to scale, the coffee cup about 20 cm in the z,x,y axis (but not a perfect square in dimensions) and the cookie about half as small as the rim of the cup in the x,y axis. Is this enough or is it required to provide the .blend file?

I hope this information is enough. I wan't the fluid to splash when in contact with the cookie. Thanks in advance.

Note: Since blender exchange took hours to upload only 20% of the file, I am providing a wetransfer link which expires in a week. Download from here: https://we.tl/t-OUIKjn5FGL

Comment: What's the dimensions of your cup and cookie? How does your cookie fall? Physics or keyframes? Also, it might help to provide a blendfile via https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @haarigertroll The cookie falls using keyframes. The cookie and coffee cup are not to scale, the coffee cup about 20 cm in the z,x,y axis (but not a perfect square in dimensions) and the cookie about half as small as the rim of the cup in the x,y axis. Is this enough or is it required to provide the .blend file?

Comment: without blend file you will be asked a lot of questions....and even then you might not get a good answer. blend file would speed up the process by far.

Comment: @Chris Ok, I'll just provide a .blend file with only th coffee cup and the cookie (Since I don't want to privide my whole scene) but any sliding animations will look weird since the scene won't be there.

Comment: you didn't provide anything. That's why your question will soon be closed

Comment: @Chris I added a wetransfer link.

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf You said you've set your coffee in the cup to _Inflow_, which makes it work like a flowing water tap... since the coffee doesn't fill itself up you should use _Geometry_ instead.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It is a nic idea to fill the coffee up with fluid, but I didn't set the fluid to geometry since if I do that the liquid doesn't even wobble when in contact with the cookie.

Comment: By the way, it took forever to upload on Blend Exchange... come on, 520 MB? Maybe you should have made a stripped down file where only the necessary parts are contained... we don't need curtains and all that to test the simulation.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I deleted the rest of the interior, but turns out that I actually forgot to save my edit of deleting the interior in the .blend file. Thanks for informing.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I've made the changes to the link.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I think you should open the link again from the question because when I open the link the file size appears to be 160 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cookie would have more effect on the coffee if you had the option *Use Effector* enabled, like you have on the cup, saucer and spoon. Maybe increase the *Sampling Substeps* to make the simulation calculate more accurate. And as I said in the comments, the coffee fluid should be set to *Geometry*, not *Inflow*. Perhaps it would also help to simulate a bit faster if you disabled the particle system for the sprinkles on the cookie.

[image: fluid sim effector]

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's a very nice splash now. But unfortunately the liquid bursts through the cup even though it has a surface thickness of 0.6 in the fluid settings.

Comment: Another question is that: will increasing the resolution divisions make the coffee loke more thin? And how should I stop the coffee from wobbling too much before contact with the cookie?

Comment: I think that's exactly your problem - the _Surface Thickness_ is **added** distance to the mesh to be considered as effector (hover your mouse pointer over the value, it explains what it's good for), and since your coffee is directly touching the cup, this 0.6 additional distance are then overlapping with the fluid - which means your liquid is inside the cup walls so they are not blocking its movement. Even with a _Surface Thickness_ of 0 which would only use the direct mesh as effector you could have this problem, since the fluid is touching the cup so due to resolution there can be overlaps.

Comment: No, it wouldn't make the coffee necessarily look more "thin", it is more detailed, finer. Maybe that's what you consider thinner. But in terms of viscosity, a higher resolution doesn't make it thinner, only more precise. Fluid simulation is quite complex, we cannot discuss all settings and effects here, what I usually do is making lots of tests with different settings to see how it affects the simulation - **before** making a longer animation with multiple effectors and moving objects etc. About the wobble: why shouldn't the coffee wobble? With the cup moving down before  this would be normal.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. But, I still don't undurstand that at a surface thickness of 0.6 when the cookie splashes into the cup the liquid does splash, but along with that it also decides to start flowing out of the walls of the cup. how should I fix that?

Comment: Ok, I understand your theory. But what steps am I supposed to take to stop the intersection?

Comment: I set the surface thickness of the cup to 2, made the liquid smaller than the cup walls, but still when the cookie splashes the fluid just bursts through the bottom of the cup. What can I do?

Comment: When I told you you don't need a _Surface Thickness_, why did you make it even bigger? The mesh has a thickness - giving it a _Surface Thickness_ makes it add up onto the mesh as I said before which results in even less space for the liquid.

Comment: Because if I don't give any surface thickness the liquid just flows through the cup, as though there was no cup at all.

Comment: Hmmm... not on my computer. I'm sorry I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: Can you share the fluid settings on the coffee and the collision settings on the cup? I made sure the liquid was not interscecting with the cup, and the cup is set as a fluid effector as a collision object with 0 surface thickness. The liquid just falls through the cup.

Comment: I deleted all animatin except the cookie flying and moved everything to start on frame 1, because this simulation is taking much too long on my PC since my CPU isn't good enough to bake this and let me work on other things at the same time. So maybe it's just because I changed a lot. I deactivated the sprinkles on the cookie and deleted everything that doesn't belong to the simulation. I set Surface Thickness to 0. Also I used 2.93.0 Beta, for the Cache I deactivated Resumable, set compression to Zip, set Sampling Substeps to 4 on all flow objects. In the domain I set Timesteps max/min to 8/2.

Comment: I added the same settings you have, made sure the liquid is not interscecting with the cup, but still it flows out even at frame 1. Can you share the .blend file you edited so I can check what is wrong in my simulation?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your fluid settings and the collision settings on the coffee cup? I need help, because the coffee bursts through the cup at some point or another (Immediately at the start of the animation without any surface thickness on the coffe cup) with/without surface thickness.

Comment: Then I will have to download it again and make it new. Problem is the next days I just have a crappy old laptop so big files or simulations will not be possible for me.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time to answer my question. Since I think this solves most of my problems I'm accepting it. Thank you again.

Comment: I found out what was causing the intersection! I just enabled 'Is Planar' on the cup collision settings and it stops interscecting!